# Pointer to array as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I'd like to instanciate my object with template parameters **only**. One of the parameters is a pointer to array, and I'm looking for the correct syntax.

```
const MyCustomType* array[2] = { &object1, &object2 };

OBJ1 < 10, 10, array > myobj1;
```

Below, a sample of the class `OBJ1`.

```
template < int a, int b, /* help ! */ >
class OBJ1
{
  public:
    OBJ1();
    ~OBJ1();

  private:
    //methods
};
```

What's the right syntax to use the third template parameter ? Is that even possible ?

Comment: That's not a pointer to an array, it's an array of [2] pointers.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley You're right :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an array of type int of size n the syntax is

```
int (*paramname)[N];
```

Or with a helper type alias

```
template<typename T>
using type = T;
```

Then

```
type<int[N]> *paramname;
```

In your case you pass a pointer to the arrays first element though, and not a pointer to the array. You need to prefix the array name with `&` to do the latter when passing the array.